# Returning wrong number of deleted records

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a issue that happens periodically. It does not depend of the quantity of the rows to be deleted. I was not able to find a patters. In another words it can happen with 2 rows, or even with 100!

Issue:
I send an array of ID's for the rows that I wish to be deleted. Deletion is always a success (Cant find the rows after). Sequalize (3.24.6) sometimes returns it deleted 0 rows, while I know for the fact it made proper deletion.

CODE:
In my repository:

```
deleteAccountProfileEntries(idArray) {
        return this.storage.deleteProfileEntries(idArray).then((erasedCount) => {
            if (idArray.length !== erasedCount) {
                throw new Error('invalid amount of records removed');
            }
        });    
    }
```

Then a call is made to storage:

```
deleteProfileEntries(profileEntryIds) {
        if (!Array.isArray(profileEntryIds)) {
            throw new Error('Expected an array as an input');
        }
        return model.profile_entries.destroy({
            where: {
                id: {
                    $in: profileEntryIds
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Issue originates in this line:

```
if (idArray.length !== erasedCount) {
                throw new Error('invalid amount of records removed');
            }
```

So, even though it deleted them, sometimes it returns deletion is zero.
I could easily remove this check, but I would like to know why.

Comment: I haven;t worked with sequelize.js but one case I can think of that this may happen is if `idArray` contains IDs which are not in the DB. So when you try to delete items in the array, it might not find a few records and only delete those which were in the DB.

Comment: That could be the reason. But I am 100% certain the id's are there. Becouse I got them via query, before attempting deletion.